# How to use imports from requirements.txt in python

Tags: python, django, import

I am attempting to use a python file in a basic web application. I have my two requirements (docx and xlrd) in my requirements.txt file, but when the python file tries to import either of the requirements, it cannot find the module. I am currently working on Repl.it. Pictures are attached.

I have tried to import only in either location, but I either fail to import the necessary packages, or I cannot refer to functions from the necessary file.

Requirements.txt -

```
xlrd==1.2.0  
docx==0.2.4  
other
```

script.py -

```
import docx  
from docx.enum.table import WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL  
import xlrd
```

error -
(continued)

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in  _call_with_frames_removed  
  File "/home/runner/main/urls.py", line 5, in <module>  
from main import views  
  File "/home/runner/main/views.py", line 3, in <module>  
from excelToDocx import transfer  
  File "/home/runner/excelToDocx.py", line 1, in <module>  
import xlrd  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd'  
exit status 1
```

Comment: Did you *activate* your local environment?

Comment: Katya from Repl.it here, just wanted to say - feel free to throw this question to repl.it/talk/ask, too.

Answer (score 9):

You need to install the packages using the command `pip install -r requirements.txt`. If they aren't installed, it isn't going to find them.

The `requirements.txt` file is simply a way to tell users of your package what requirements there are for your program, and then let them install all of them easily through [PyPi](https://pypi.org/) using the `pip` program. It doesn't actually tell python to install them for you.

Comment: Thanks for insight, I ended up locally hosting the server, rather than using the Repl.it host, and this fixed my issue.